# React-native: textAlign: 'right' not styling correctly

Tags: javascript, css, text, react-native

I'm quite new to react-native css-styling.. and have the following code:

```
 <Text>
<Text style={(styles.author, { textAlign: "left" })}>
    {question.view_count + " views\t" + question.comment_count}
    {question.comment_count > 1 || question.comment_count == 0
        ? " comments"
        : " comment"}
</Text>
<Text style={{ textAlign: "right" }}>
    {question.solution_count > 0
        ? question.solution_count + " solutions"
        : " Solve this"}
</Text>
</Text>;
```

The problem is the second "textAlign: 'right' " isn't working - the text is still on the left. I want the text to be on the same line, but (obviously) the second text-object on the right.

Any hints? thanks!

**edit**
output looks like this:
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: What does the output HTML/CSS look like?

Comment: @Paulie_D see my edit

Comment: No...not an image of the result...the actual HTML/CSS If that bottom line is just one element...you need to break it into two.

Comment: @Paulie_D is that possible in react-native? maybe my tagging of the question is off..

Comment: I don't know...without seeing what is actually being output as HTML/CSS it's hard to offer solutions. I suspect that this is just outputing one element with two text strings one after the other. In which as you can't align them differently.

Comment: Just FYI - `<Text style={styles.author, {textAlign: 'left'}}>` should actually be `<Text style={[styles.author, {textAlign: 'left'}]}>` you need to put overriding styles in an array, with the second item overriding the first :)

Answer (score 113, accepted):

Work-around -

```
<View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row'}}>
  <View style={{flex: 1}}>
    <Text>4 Views 0 Comments</Text>
  </View>
  <View style={{flex: 1}}>
    <Text style={{textAlign: 'right'}}>Solve This</Text>
  </View>
</View>
```

Answer (score 16):

you can use below code snippet for aligning your text on right side of view:

```
<View style={{justifyContent: 'space-between'}}>
   <Text style={{alignSelf: 'flex-end'}}> Hello </Text>
</View>
```

Comment: While I appreciate new answers, I don't quite understand why this question suddendly after 3 years has 2 new answers within 1.5days... any insights?

Comment: @dv3 maybe at present developers are using StackOverflow quite often :D

Answer (score 8):

Give width 100% to your text tag so that you make sure it stretches it's full width, then give texalign right. This might work.

Answer (score 4):

I found that because i was using a full width button (already `alignSelf: 'stretch'`) it caused the text content to stretch vertically not horizontally... i found that using `flex: 1` on the text element instead seemed to work as intended. 
Example:

```
finishButtonText: {
    textAlign: "center",
    flex: 1
} as StyleProp<TextStyle>
```

with .tsx / .jsx:

```
<Button style={{alignSelf: 'stretch'}}>
    <Text style={styles.finishButtonText}>
        Test
    </Text>
</Button>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
style={{marginLeft:'auto' }}
```

Will works with button, items etc.

Answer (score 4):

Some times I use this

```
<View style={{flexDirection:'row-reverse'}}>
  <Text>This text is aligned right</Text>
</View>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had an issue on Android where a string wrapped by two `<Text>` components was not respecting the **`textAlign`** property like so

```
<Text>
  <Text style={{textAlign: "center"}}> // on Android this wasn't working
    Solution
  </Text>
</Text>
```

I replaced the outer Text component with the fragment syntax and it started to work again:

```
<>
  <Text style={{textAlign: "center"}}>
    Solution that worked for me
  </Text>
</>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try adding below style to your text component.

```
<Text style={{ alignSelf: 'flex-start', textAlign: 'right' }}>Anoop</Text>
```

Comment: What does this add compared to the other answers?

Comment: @dv3 this helped me in case of RTL orientation. For me the text was taking full width so giving textAlign: 'right' wasn't so, the above solution worked because after adding flex-start the text component width reduced to the text size and textAligned worked. I hope you understand, please let me know if you need me.

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
textAlign: "justify"
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add justifyContent: 'space-between' in the outer  and the textAlign: 'right' will work.

```
<View style={{flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between'}}>
   <Card.Title style={{fontSize: 16, textAlign: 'left'}}>Participating tasks</Card.Title>
   <Card.Title style={{fontSize: 12, textAlign: 'right'}}>View More</Card.Title>        
</View>
```

Comment: so you mean like the already accepted answer? What's the difference?